# VBA- How to set a workbook type variable when i only know a partial workbook name

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have several workbooks open. One of them is sometimes named "trade1", sometimes "trade2", or anything else but always starting "trade". I'm trying to set a variable so that regardless of the name if it's open and it starts with "trade" that workbook will now be the variable. So that throughout the macro I can refer to that book and use it for things such as Trade.activate to select that book. Here is my current code where I am getting a Run-Time Error '9': subscript out of range error:

```
Dim Trade as Workbook

Set Trade = workbooks("trade" & "*" & ".xls")
```

I know this can be done with a function but was hoping it could done a simpler way. Is this possible or am I on a fools errand?

Comment: If you only have one workbook open, as you say in your question's first sentence, you can just use `ActiveWorkbook` instead of `Trade` (or `Set Trade = ActiveWorkbook`).  It's only when you have more than one workbook open that you need to do anything special.

Comment: If the Workbook you are running the code is in the workbook in question whose name may be different, you can use `ThisWorkbook`, which is slightly better than `ActiveWorkbook`, IMO. If the `trade...` workbook is the only *other* workbook you have open (besides one where code runs) see ScottCraner's answer below.

Comment: @YowE3K Rereading my question I did make a mistake. I have at least one of workbook open when running this macro.

Comment: @jbaboon - I have updated the question slightly to make it clearer that it isn't a single workbook situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can loop through the open workbooks and find the correct one then set the variable:

```
Dim Trade As Workbook
Dim t As Workbook

For Each t In Workbooks
    If Left(t.Name, 5) = "trade" Then
        Set trade = Workbooks(t.Name)
    End If
Next t
```

Comment: Thank you, This is exactly what I was looking for. I presume I can use the same code for other workbook names as well. Just change out what is in the quotes and create a new variable(similar to Dim Trade) for other workbooks?

Comment: @jbaboon yes just change to what you are looking for.